# How to display rotated/vertical text in the Android webview

Tags: android, html, css, webview

I'd like to display text going up/rotated 90 degrees counter-clockwise in the Android stock webview

Answer (score 0):

Hat-tip to [ScottGale.com](http://scottgale.com/blog/css-vertical-text/2010/03/01/) where I found the clockwise example. This is tested in the Gingerbread browser.

```
p.css-vertical-text {
 -webkit-transform:rotate(270deg);
 -moz-transform:rotate(270deg);
 -o-transform:rotate(270deg);
 white-space:nowrap;
 display:block;
 position:absolute;
 width:24px;
 left:24px;
 bottom:0;
 font-size:24px;
 font-weight:normal;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. So I'd just put that in a < STYLE > tag, then whenever I want to use it I'd do < P class= css-vertical-text > ?

Comment: Offhand I would say change "bottom:0" to "top:0" but more tweaking might be necessary. I'm not anywhere I could test that at the moment.

Comment: top:0 doesn't align it to the top, it starts it at the top though.